# How to save the contents of a file system on to a file

Tags: unix, filesystems, fuse

What is the best practice to save and retrieve a file system in UNIX. Say I have a filesystem at /mnt/vin, my requirement is to save the contents to a file. How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried this far? Could you show us some code which does not work, so we can then help you to improve it?

Comment: I have implemented an in memory FS using fuse. I wanted to make it persistent by writing contents into a file. Had no clue on how to do it. I dont have any code implemented for saving the FS yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to backup the complete FS(data and metadata), mostly commonly use `dd if=/path/do/dev of=/path/to/file bs=1024`

Comment: Thank you. This should help me to get started!